# Problem getting last chunk in a while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

So it's been awhile since i did any PHP and to be honest, this question feels kinda dumb. But my head is just stuck thinking about how to get last chunk in a file.

My while loop reads a file, line by line and after 10 lines it should execute a code. Problem occures when there's 51 lines. How do i reach the last line?

The file is over 300 mb so I cannot load it into memory (array).

```
while ($row = fgets($handle))
{
    $chunk[] = array_combine($feed_product_arraykeys, explode("\t", $row));

    if(count($chunk) == 10)
    {
        echo count($chunk) . '<br>';

        // Initiate code

        unset($chunk);
    }
}
```

Best Regards

Comment: What's the exact problem? Can you share some code that triggers your problem?

Comment: So, what's the **exact** problem with having 51 lines here? That the `echo` does not occur? Then why not run it directly after the loop once if `count($chunk) > 0`?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternate way.  Just read the file into an array and chunk it into chunks of 10  The remaining will be in the last chunk:

```
foreach(array_chunk(file('/path/to/file'), 10) as $row) {
    $chunk[] = array_combine($feed_product_arraykeys, explode("\t", $row));

    echo count($chunk) . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Hello AbraCadaver, I forgot to mention that the file is 300 mb so I cannot load it all into a array. I have to read one line at a time for this. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Either way at the end of your loop or mine `$chunk` will contain all lines of the file anyway.

Comment: It would if I didnt use unset() to free up memory, but I have to use that sadly.

Answer (score -1):

So i actually fixed it by counting number of rows in the file. I thought it would be slow but its actually fast, even on a 300 mb file with 130k rows.

```
// Count number of lines in feed
$feed_row_count = count_lines_in_file("tmp/56.csv");

$row_counter = 0;
$feed_handle = fopen("tmp/56.csv", "r");
while ($row = fgets($feed_handle))
{
    $row_counter++;

    $chunk[] = array_combine($feed_product_arraykeys, explode("\t", $row));

    if(count($chunk) == 25 || $feed_row_count == $row_counter)
    {
        echo count($chunk) . '<br>';

        // Initiate SQL

        unset($chunk);
    }
}
```